# How to get the extract the elements above the diagnal and store it in an array

Tags: python

I created a matrix using:

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for z in range(5)]
```

I am trying to extract the elements above the diagnal and store it in an array.

For example:

```
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
U=[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]

A=[1,4,9]
  [0,1,2]
  [2,3,6]

U=[4,9,2]
```

Comment: What do you get, what do you expect? Draw it!

Comment: I think your U should be U=[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1] ?

Comment: I am getting a matrix as shown in the example and i dont know how to get U

Comment: But is your U correct as i can see it should be 0,0,1,1,0 first column and then '0,0,0,1,0' which row or column is this ?

Comment: Still can't get it which row or column is 0,0,0,1,1. The last 5 digits in your U. Can you add 2 more matrix in your question just showing the data or row/column you want to extract from this matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use List Comprehensions.

```
from random import randrange

Matrix = [[randrange(10) for x in range(5)] for z in range(5)]
>>>Matrix
[[6, 3, 7, 9, 3], [8, 6, 4, 0, 4], [0, 0, 1, 3, 2], [7, 7, 2, 3, 7], [3, 3, 5, 6, 3]]

[Matrix[i][j] for i in range(0,5) for j in range(i+1,5)]
[3, 7, 9, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7]
```

Comment: this is a nicer solution indeed! +1

Answer (score 0):

So here is a Solution, i changed your matrix to generate any random numbers so that you can see better which numbers are taken into account. TRIU = Triangle Upper is the function that takes a Matrix in your given format and takes the Upper Triangle, which is above the diagonal.

```
#import numpy as np
from random import randrange

Matrix = [[randrange(10) for x in range(5)] for z in range(5)]

def triu(matrix):
    length = len(matrix[0])
    U = list()
    diagLine = 0

    for row in Matrix:
        length -= 1
        colCounter = 0
        for col in row:
            if colCounter > diagLine:
                U.append(col)
            colCounter += 1
        diagLine += 1

    return U



#print np.matrix(Matrix)
print triu(Matrix)
```

**Result:**

```
[[0 0 2 4 0]
 [6 4 8 9 0]
 [6 2 2 3 0]
 [2 9 6 5 5]
 [1 5 8 9 2]]
[0, 2, 4, 0, 8, 9, 0, 3, 0, 5]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```